# Symfony: CountryType translation does not work on remote server

Tags: symfony

I want to display list of countries in arabic so as mentioned in the title it works fine on localhost but not on my remote server !!
I have set arabic as default language in my config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: ar

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

This is the list on local machine:
[image]
And this is what I get on remote server:
[image]
And this is my FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fullName', TextType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('country', CountryType::class)
            ->add($builder->create(
                'birthday', TextType::class, array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->addModelTransformer(new DateTransformer('Y-m-d'))
            )
            ->add('username', TextType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
            ))
        ;

        if($builder->getData()->getId() != null){
            $builder->add('image', AttachmentWithoutDescriptionType::class);
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the php.ini file on your remote server for the following param's value: `intl.default_locale`. CountryType uses `Locale::getDefault()` to guess a user's locale.

If you're using the Apache web server, your can put a param into your .htaccess file to override php.ini value.

```
php_value intl.default_locale ar_AR
```

Or simply hardcode the value into your front controllers (app.php, app_dev.php and commands)

```
\Locale::setDefault('ar_AR');
```

If you need to change locale dynamically, you should implement a locale listener and set desired locale using the below code snippet.

Comment: and how can I change it without touching `php.ini` ? I don't have access to it. How can I force CountryType to use always the arabic language ?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I get this error when I hardcode it in the app_dev.php: `the Symfony\Component\Intl\Locale\Locale::setDefault() is not implemented. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.`

Comment: Please make sure that your PHP Intl extension is installed and loaded. And you should use a \Locale class from a root namespace, which is also a part of an Intl extension.